# Athena DISTINCT on ONE row

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table like following

```
| date_partition|   app_id | location_id  | a    | b    |  c       |      d     |app_type   |   ru_today|   ru_this_week|   ru_this_month   |mau    |execution_count|
|   9/20/21     | 17ccc103 |    56a7d682  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   TRUE  |      402    |
|   9/20/21     | 17ccc103 |    56a7d682  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   FALSE |      402    |
|   9/20/21     | 9056ac49 |    f4494101  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   TRUE  |      291    |
|   9/20/21     | 9056ac49 |    f4494101  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   FALSE |      291    |
|   9/20/21     | cf98b87d |    59a8f889  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   FALSE  |  FALSE        |  TRUE        | TRUE  |      1      |
|   9/20/21     | cf98b87d |    59a8f889  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   TRUE  |      1      |
|   9/20/21     | cf98b87d |    59a8f889  | TRUE | TRUE |   FALSE  |    FALSE   |   WEBHOOK |   TRUE   |    TRUE         |  TRUE        |   FALSE |      1      |
```

I would like to get a unique count for each item and for each flag(a,b and c being true).

For example

```
9056ac49-5c29-4366-9eb2-64576cb2a9af | f4494101 | 291 | 291 | 291
cf98b87d-3605-42a2-85b9-2993956fe927 | 59a8f889 | 1   | 1   | 1
```

Problem is when I do Group BY, I have double counts(Since 2 rows have value as TRUE, but I want them to by counted once).

How do I just get one row for each? Not sure if I can use `WINDOW BY` here

**[UPDATE]**
Issue is with double count. For example
[image]

here I need to count this only once(i.e just 402). If I do conditional count, I still count it twice(804)

Comment: can you please provide data and desired output in text form?

Comment: I updated. done :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "conditional" sum with case statement:

```sql
SELECT date_partition, app_id, location_id, 
    sum(case when a then execution_count else 0 end) as count_a,
    sum(case when b then execution_count else 0 end) as count_b,
    sum(case when c then execution_count else 0 end) as count_c
FROM dataset
GROUP BY date_partition, app_id, location_id
```

Possibly using it on subselect with `distinct` on fields of interest.

**UPD**

To exclude "duplicates" you need to filter them out first. For example using subselect as I mentioned before:

```sql
SELECT date_partition, app_id, location_id, 
    sum(case when a then execution_count else 0 end) as count_a,
    sum(case when b then execution_count else 0 end) as count_b,
    sum(case when c then execution_count else 0 end) as count_c,
FROM (
   SELECT distinct date_partition, app_id, location_id, a, b, c, execution_count 
   FROM dataset
)
GROUP BY date_partition, app_id, location_id
```

Comment: issue is with double count with this approach. I updated the problem statement

Comment: @Yogi check the last line in my answer - "Possibly using it on subselect with distinct on fields of interest." Basically you should use `FROM (select date_partition, app_id, location_id,app_id, a,b,c from dataset)` instead of `FROM dataset`

Comment: but this will only work if all values are same. but in my case just one of the column is toggled and I want to ignore that one

Comment: @Yogi TBH not fully following. Can you please provide the text inputs?

Comment: I updated the table with text. I cant do DISTINCT. If you look at my UPDATE, I get both rows if I do DISTINCT, but I want only 1

Comment: @Yogi my query with provided data gives the expected output - `9/20/21 9056ac49 f4494101 291 291 0`  (though 3 rows one for each of 291, 402 and 1 counts)

Comment: Thats because you are not selecting `ru_today`, `ru_this_week` , `ru_month` and `mau` from subquery.  if you look carefully, `'mau` gets flipped and that is the main issue. how do I remove those

Comment: @Yogi but the expected result does not have those fields why would I select them?

Comment: oh sorry. my bad. it should have those as well

Comment: @Yogi what is rule to determine duplication then? What is an unique "id" for count for `a`?  `date_partition + app_id  + location_id `?

Comment: yes. correct. I just need it to counted once